# An object of mass 2 kg is released 1000 meters above the ground.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming the force due to air resistance is proportional to tthe square of the velocity of the object with proportionality constant k = 19.62 $kg/sec$ and the gravitational force is 9.81 $met/sec^2$, determine the velocity of the object 0.5 seconds after it is released. Set up the appropriate differential equation and show your solution technique in solving the differential equation.

Comment: What is the context of this question. What have you tried.

Comment: Meanwhile I think your units are wrong for $k$. As the units $kv^2$ where $v$ is the velocity, are (kg)(meters)/(second$)^2$ this implies that $k$ must have units kg/meter

Comment: I have tried $m \dfrac{dv}{dt} = -mg - bv^2$. Then I divided by $-b$. I'm really just confused how to the equation of motion of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The ODE using Newton’s second law is: $\frac{dv}{dt}+ \frac{k}{m}v^2=g$.

$\frac{dv}{dt}=0\Rightarrow k{v_0}^2=mg$.

> Resolution: Now we put this expression into ODE. It comes:  $mdv=k({v_0}^2-v^2)dt\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{v^2-v_0^2}=-\frac{k}{m}dt$ then:
>   $$\int_{0}^{v}{\frac{dv}{v^2-v_0^2}}dv=\int_{0}^{\tau}{\frac{-k}{m}}dt$$ $\Rightarrow$
>   $$\frac{1}{v_0}arctanh {({\frac{v}{v_0}})}=\frac{k}{m}\tau$$ $\Rightarrow$ $$v=v_0\tanh(\frac{kv_0}{m}\tau)$$
>   Recall $v_0=\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}$

Replace $\tau$ by $0,5s$ to deduce the needed speed.